# best practice for ingesting pubsub payloads into Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I am looking for best practices on how to ingest various payloads coming from a single subscription(one topic) into Big Query. The data can be ingested in raw format but need to be structured in more tabular form and mapped to published layer for business consumption. I was googling some options but need guidance on designing pubsub message ingestion to publication solution in real time.

1. Should I simply dump all the data keeping similar structure to the message in raw as string or Json or should I structure attributes into columns/structures/arrays what are the pros and cons
2. does it make sense to split the subscription into multiple filtered subsciptions and map them to multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: You know the possible columns (JSON keys) you can receive

I would structure the Pub/Sub message into columns (and if your JSON is pretty nested, take advantage of BigQuery's nested structures)

Case 2: You don't know the possible columns you can receive or suspect they will frequently change

Separate it into columns in your target BigQuery tables as much as you can, and dump the rest as a raw string in a column that you can always parse later with BigQuery SQL.

Also, in case you haven't seen it already: you can now push messages straight form Pub/Sub to BigQuery (without going through Dataflow, which is great at parsing the Pub/Sub messages but can tend to be costly): https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/pub-sub-launches-direct-path-to-bigquery-for-streaming-analytics